# Is there a state mutator observer in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tl;dr -- I want to fire a callback whenever the state changes in a component

---

I have a component that mutates `this.props.items` and fires `this.props.onChange` on every mutation.  I'm currently doing something like this:

```
removeItem(ix) {
  const items = this.state.items.slice();
  items.splice(ix, 1);
  this.setState({ items });
  this.triggerOnChange();
}
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to remove the manual call to `triggerOnChange` and instead do it whenever `this.state.items` is updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override `setState`, if you want to wrap the state change:

```
setState(state) {
  console.log("New state - before: ", state);
  const retVal = super.setState(state);
  console.log("New state - after");
  return retVal;
}
```

(That may be overkill, I don't think `setState` is documented to have a return value; but frustratingly, as far as I can tell, it's not documented *not* to...)

Example:

```js
class MyThingy extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {...props};
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.update()}>
      <div>{this.state.title}</div>
      {this.state.items.map(e => (
            <div>{e}</div>
      ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  update() {
    this.setState({
      items: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      title: "After"
    });
  }
  
  setState(state) {
    console.log("New state - before: ", state);
    const retVal = super.setState(state);
    console.log("New state - after");
    return retVal;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyThingy items={[]} title="Before - click me" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Alternately, you might turn this on its head and look at [MobX](http://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/).

Comment: Looks like it should work, thanks!  FYI what I did: `setState(state) { super.setState(state, (state.items !== this.state.items) ? this.triggerOnChange : noop); }`

Comment: @zyklus: No worries! (And I figured out what I was doing wrong. Silly boy, I was using `props`, not `state`!)

Comment: the `triggerOnChange` is for firing `this.props.onChange()`, not a rendering update

Answer (score 4):

`this.setState` takes two parameter, first is object (state) and second is a callback (optional)

```
this.setState({...}, function(){
  console.log('changed')
})
```

From [`Spec`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> The second parameter is an optional callback function that will be
>   executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered

Comment: Cool, good to know!  This still has a similar issue though in that I need to manually add `this.triggerOnChange` as the callback.  I'm looking for something like a state observer so that I can just do `this.on('stateChange', ...)`

Comment: This is still a useful answer for others coming to this question with slightly different needs, nice one!